# Host VueJs 3 on IIS Virtual Directory

Tags: iis, vuejs3, virtual-directory

I'm new to vuejs. I developed aspnet core api with vuejs as frontend. my application works fine locally but having difficulty to have it deployed on IIS for a specific configuration.

On IIS for my application(say abc.com) files directory is like following

[image: physical folder structure]

And on IIS it should appear as follows

[image]

can someone help with the steps required to configure this as above?

Only way I was able to configure and run this application by following steps below

1. create a new website from IIS, point to the App folder
2. once website is created right click on the website and add application and point to the api folder
3. create a web.config file to use rewrite url
   but above approach changes the IIS view as following and I don't have permission to do that

[image]
thanks in advance for reading this post.

UPDATE:

when I try access abc.com/app/welcome from browser, I can see css and js files are still looking inside root directory

[image]

I used a web.config file inside "App" directory. following url rewrite I used

```
      <rule name="Handle custom 404/500" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(Api)" negate="true" />
          
        </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
```

thanks again for your time on this

Comment: This link should help you: [https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/59b9d6/virtual-hosting-or-virtual-directory-using-iis](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/59b9d6/virtual-hosting-or-virtual-directory-using-iis).

Comment: Are you trying to have API and WEB like  abc.com/api, abc.com/app? Let us know the way you want to navigate web and API?

Comment: @ShamithWimukthi I'm trying to have api like abc.com/api and app like abc.com, if possible, thank you for your input on this

Comment: Have you tried with Application Request Routing ?add web.config to root domain file path there you can configure rewrite request, which will rewrite  abc.com to abc.com/web

Comment: yes I used an Web.Config. With postman I can hit api endpoints. But for the frontend when I go to abc.com/app/welcome (component), css and js files are still trying to access from root directory. I am updating the question with more screenshots

Comment: Try using failed request tracing to see details about 404 error.